# PHP MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Can someone help why this sql database gave me error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */' when i import this sql to my server?

```js
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.7.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jan 11, 2012 at 01:22 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.56
-- PHP Version: 5.2.9

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `testdb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `members`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `salary` int(11),
  `student_year` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `members`
--

INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `username`, `name`, `salary`, `student_year`) VALUES
(1, '11John', 'John Smith', 12000, NULL),

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Replace the comma with a semi-colon :INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `username`, `name`, `salary`, `student_year`) VALUES
(1, '11John', 'John Smith', 12000, NULL),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Might be a Semicolon error at end of your insert Query
pls check it!!

```
INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `username`, `name`, `salary`, `student_year`) VALUES (1, '11John', 'John Smith', 12000, NULL);
```